# Generate multiple XML files based on database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby, xml-builder

Can someone provide an example of using Builder to create multiple XML files from a SQL database. I can easily create one containing the entire database as in here...

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
   format.xml { @rides = Rides.find(:all) }
  end
end
```

This will create a file called index.xml based on a file I created called index.xml.builder which contains the following code

```
xml.instruct!
xml.rides do
@rides.each do |ride|
  xml.item("togive" => ride.togive, "totake" => ride.totake, "howlong" => ride.howlong,       "isoffer" => ride.isoffer, "id" => ride.id, "contact" => ride.contact)
 end
end
```

Here are the only lines in my routes.rb

```
map.resources :rides
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
```

This works fine, but how would I create a new file that contains the last element in Rides?

Thanks

edit: changed from format.rss to format.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, but you could have another method in your controller that returns the last ride:

```
def last
  respond_to do |format| 
    format.xml { @last_ride = Rides.last } 
  end 
end
```

And then in the view template `last.xml.builder` you could have something like:

```
xml.instruct! 
xml.rides do 
  xml.item("togive" => @last_ride.togive, "totake" => @last_ride.totake etc...) 
end
```

If you went with this approach then you'd need to modify your `config/routes.rb` file to add a new [collection route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) for the `list` action:

```
map.resources :rides, :collection => { :last => :get }
```

- This would then let you access the route using http://localhost:3000/rides/last.xml

Alternatively you could simply make the `find` call within the controller's `index` method conditional so that it fetches all rides or the last ride as appropriate. In this case you should be able to re-use the existing `index.xml.builder` view template because it will just output a collection that happens to only ever contain one ride.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I am trying to do. It should work, but It can never find the route for it. So this would then be accessible via the web from say http://something:3000/latest or http://something:3000/rides/latest ??

Comment: It depends what your `config/routes.rb` file looks like. Can you edit your question to include the contents of it please.

Comment: I'm guessing I need to add another line to routes.rb in order to it to recognize the latest method in the controller?

Comment: Also when i go to rides/latest i get the following error....
    
    Unknown action

    No action responded to show. Actions: create, index, latest, and new

Comment: Excellent thank you for your help! I knew it was probably just a routes problem...